# Stream PhantomJS output to frontend application

Tags: php, html, websocket, phantomjs

I have application with PHP backend. I know how to get output from simple phantomjs app using just PHP.

```
$response = exec('/path/to/phantomjs myscript.js');
```

## The problem is...

my PhantomJS app works very long time (with loops) and outputs current progress and actions that going inside script for monitoring purposes.

What I need to do is,

1. To execute phantomjs script when user presses some button
2. To stream it's output using php / websocket / html5 sse (server sent events) until it finishes

## Ideas

I'm sure that PHP is not proper option for this purpose because long polling is not an option at all.

Because of server push support of websocket / [html5 sse](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), I think one of them will be suitable.

After googling for a long time, I found this little app https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd

but not sure that this is proper way to do what I need.

Can't figure out, how to stream output properly from PhantomJS app into frontend app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So have you been able to come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS has a built-in server, here's [a nice answer about using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30715948/2715393).

But if you want to use Websockets, it's doable too, I personally found using Express.js with Socket.io is a breeze. Here's a short concept code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var iosocket;

// save websocket connection for later use
io.on("connection", function(socket){
    iosocket = socket;
});

// GET request starts PhantomJS work, no matter how long
app.get("/launch-long-phantomjs-process", function(req, res){

    res.send("I'm on it!");

    var info = [];
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        child    = spawn('/usr/bin/phantomjs', ['/path/to/phantomjs/script.js']);

    console.log("Spawned parser");

    // Save incoming data from PhantomJS
    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        info.push(data.toString());
    });

    // Just in case of errors
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    // When PhantomJS exits, we can finally send
    // collected data to browser via a websocket
    child.on('close', function (code) {
        iosocket.emit("info", info);
    });    

});
```

In this scheme PhantomJS just spits scraped data back to node via `console.log`. Of course one can use more sophisticated way of bridging PhantomJS and node, like [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) or [node-phantomjs-simple](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple).