# Is it possible to invoke PhantomJS through the browser?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, phantomjs, server-side

I'm trying to generate server-side images of a portion of my DOM, and then serve those images up to users from my server once they're created.

I'm curious as to the implementation possibilities of PhantomJS, as I don't entirely understand its purpose beyond exploring and testing. I get that it is a self-contained binary, and I've got it running basic apps like in their tutorials. But is there a way to do something along the lines of the following?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test.</h1>
        <button>Rasterize!</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        $('button').click(function() {
            // invoke PhantomJS here to generate PNG of this page
        });
    </script>
<html>
```

Specifically, I'm looking at doing something along the lines of:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js https://localhost:9999/test.html test.png
```

Someone, please, school me!

Comment: You can't do that on the client side, no. Not unless you wanted to compile WebKit to JavaScript (hard, will result in a gigantic file, generally bad idea). You can send a request to a server that runs PhantomJS, though.

Comment: PhantomJS is gradually going to go away now that Chrome has a headless mode. But in either case there's no way to run it from the browser.

Comment: Plerase have a look at [How to run PhantomJS as a server and call it remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713657/how-to-run-phantomjs-as-a-server-and-call-it-remotely) It's the closest thing to what you would like to do.