# How can I automate the web from a web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, phantomjs, webautomation

I'm attempting to create my first ever full-blown website. The site will host a form that takes a user's link and scrapes the inputted website. Besides scraping, I'm also looking for click and input functionality (for future projects).

I managed to create a PhantomJS function that scrapes a website depending on the parameters. However, I have absolutely no idea how to implement this into my Xampp server which locally hosts my website...PhantomJS only runs off of a command line as far as I'm aware.

Is it even possible to host a PhantomJS program on a website? Should I be using something else, such as NodeJS or another language? Ultimately, I'll go learn anything in order to make this happen.

Any ideas/suggestions are much appreciated. I apologize if this question seems dumb.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815652/is-it-possible-to-invoke-phantomjs-through-the-browser
Read comments under the question, maybe it will help you.

Comment: But I believe you can write webscraper yourself without PhantomJS, so you can do it from browser.

Comment: @Konowy Thank you. I spent some time investigating the PhantomJS server module, but I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for (difficult to send multiple requests at once). How would I go about writing my own webscraper? Even if you have so much as a link to a guide I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Here you have some guide https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3
It's written for node.js, but I think you can use it on web.

Comment: @Konowy thank you.